# an error while "installing the image_view"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, image, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i use ubuntu 12.04 & ROS(groovy)
i want to use wstool and catkin_make to get the package:image_view. but there are some problems:

```
    cit@cit-ThinkStation-S20:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package cv_bridge.

  Set cv_bridge_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for cv_bridge.  The file will have one of the following names:

    cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
    cv_bridge-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package image_geometry.

  Set image_geometry_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for image_geometry.  The file will have one of the following names:

    image_geometryConfig.cmake
    image_geometry-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package image_transport.

  Set image_transport_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for image_transport.  The file will have one of the following names:

    image_transportConfig.cmake
    image_transport-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package nodelet.

  Set nodelet_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  nodelet.  The file will have one of the following names:

    nodeletConfig.cmake
    nodelet-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package stereo_msgs.

  Set stereo_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for stereo_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    stereo_msgsConfig.cmake
    stereo_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'humanoid_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(humanoid_msgs/humanoid_msgs)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'humanoid_nav_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(humanoid_msgs/humanoid_nav_msgs)
-- Generating .msg files for action humanoid_nav_msgs/ExecFootsteps /home/cit/catkin_ws/src/humanoid_msgs/humanoid_nav_msgs/action/ExecFootsteps.action
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:252 (message):
  Could not find 'share/actionlib_msgs/cmake/actionlib_msgs-msg-paths.cmake'
  (searched in '/home/cit/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy').
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  humanoid_msgs/humanoid_nav_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:29 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99366/an-error-while-%22installing-the-image_view%22/) by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you do not have all of `image_view`'s dependencies, based on lines like this:

```
...
Could not find a configuration file for package cv_bridge.
...
Could not find a configuration file for package image_geometry.
...
Could not find a configuration file for package image_transport.
...
Could not find a configuration file for package nodelet.
...
Could not find a configuration file for package stereo_msgs.
...
```

You should either use rosinstall_generator and wstool to get them from source, which I describe in this answer:

http://answers.ros.org/question/92806/setting-workspace-for-rosws/?answer=92906#post-id-92906

or use rosdep to get them installed from debians:

```
rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0